# Relaunch the current Activity after Login Activity in Android

Tags: android, login-control

In my application when I click proceed button on an Activity, it checks whether the user is logged in or not. If the user is logged in, it goes to next page (SomeActivity) with all recorded information on the Activity it was previously, but if the user is not logged in  LoginActivity will be launched and then after login next step will be proceeded.

But the problem is that after the login success on LoginActivity I am firing an intent of the HomeActivity which I don't want to do. After the success of the login, the same Activity (From where LoginActivity was launched) should be open.

Comment: Let me clarify first,If the user doesn't logged in it will redirect to login screen,if suppose user has been logged in it will redirect to home screen right.so once app closed and open if the user is in logged directly u need to redirect to home screen right?

Comment: Share your code!

Comment: No...let me explain it with an example, suppose there is a recharge app, in which you have entered all the required  fields and going to proceed for payment but without logged in you can not go ahead so login activity will launch and if login is success again the last activity with all information will be launched.

Comment: Let me explain. FIRST you log in. AND THEN you start the main Activity.

Comment: No, just like flipkart or any shopping app, login is not mandatory for searching item so user can skip the login page while going to MainActivity but when you are going to purchase any item, at that you will have to login  first, the same scenario is in my app,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling startActivity(), call finish() if login success which will lead you to the previous activity from the back-stack.

Also don't call finish() after calling startActivity() to open LoginActivity.

Answer (score 0):

When on click you check that user is not logged in use following intent to open login activity

```
Intent intent =new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

when login is successful in login activtiy call following and the last activity in the activity stack will be started.

```
LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: what about the data which was stored on that activity,because after calling finish() on LoginActivity, onCreate() of the first activity will be called again and the data which i have saved previously will be deleted

Comment: after calling finish() on LoginActivity OnStart() method of the previous activity will be called and you can save data OnStop() and retrieve it onStart()